# Set C# Inline Expressions in ASP.NET Controls On Server-Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

Is it possible to programatically insert C# Inline Expressions as the values for ASP.NET Controls in your server-side code?

I'm currently using a `DataList` to display a lot of data in a table. I want to be able to dynamically change the columns of that table, so I need to be able to edit what controls are in its `ItemTemplate`.

However, in addition to editing the controls in the `ItemTemplate`, I need to be able to alter the value that is binded to each control in the template, because I want to dynamically change what is being displayed.

So what I currently have is a static table that doesn't change:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dataList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dataList_OnSelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="peopleData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="NameLink" OnClientClick="onPageUpdate()" CommandName="Select" Text='<%# Eval(this.Name) %>' ForeColor='<%# Eval("this.NameColor") %>' runat=Server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("this.Values[\"Age\"]") %>' ForeColor='<%# Eval("this.ValueColors[\"Age\"]") %>' runat="Server">
                </td>
                // OTHER COLUMNS WITH DIFFERENT DATA
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
// OBJECT DATA SOURCE CODE
```

I know how to dynamically add Controls to the ASPX web page. However, I don't know how to add the inline expressions.

I've tried doing the following but it doesn't work because of the type mismatches:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "<%# Eval(\"this.Values[\\\"Age\\\"]\") %>";
label.ForeColor = "<%# Eval(\"this.ValueColors[\\\"Age\\\"]\") %>";
```

Is there a way of achieving this or doing something similar?

My only other option that I can think of right now is to scrap using the `DataList` and `ItemTemplate` and just generate each row myself.. That's a lot more coding versus just using the `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help you, but look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It is showing using of the hand-written exposure of properties. If your property were always call "magic" and you return the appropriate value for *magic* within your code would that get you what you need?